# How to show a "Saved!" message after Redirect() is made..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redirect

I am currently working in a MVC4 project.

Imagine the following scenario:

---

**(1)** The user is allowed to add data to multiple tables and after that needs to confirm by hitting the Submit. `<input type="submit" value="" id="saveBtn" title="Save" />` The reason there is no value is because I have CSS applied to the Submit.

**(2)** After that, to avoid a previous bug to prevent a refresh of the page to duplicate data, I need to Redirect the user in my Controller: `return Redirect("Edit?Id=" + id);`

**(3)** After the Redirect() is made, *I want to show a simple message that says "Saved!" with a delay of 5 seconds*. I do not want an `alert("Saved!");`.

---

I currently got a pseudo-solution working but not preferred. It's an simple click function in jQuery:

CSS

```
.successMessage {
    color: darkgreen;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="successMessage" style="display: none;">Saved!</div>
```

JS

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function () {
    $(".successMessage").delay(500).show(0);
});
```

---

The problem is that, since I `Redirect();` the user, my message cannot be delayed with this "solution". And after a `Redirect();` is made, the message will not show up again.

What is a better approach in order to get a 'delayed' message? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a TempData in your submit action,and show the delay message in your view by confirm if TempData has value when page is ready.

Action:

```
//save info
TempData["Message"]="Saved!";
return Redirect("Edit?Id=" + id)
```

View:

```
string message=TempData["Message"]==null?"":TempData["Message"].ToString();
@if(message!="")
{
    <div class="successMessage" style="display: none;">@message</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".successMessage").delay(500).show(0);
      })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the syntax is wrong for `string message=TempData["Message"]==null?"":TempData["Message"].ToString();` sine I cannot resolve symbol 'message' in my View.

Comment: @urbz Use var message instead of string message.

Comment: @Ash Thanks, but I got it working! :) **jarvanJiang** how silly of me I tried doing this inside a paragraph and that caused the issue. Otherwise your answer worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to show notification messages is to use `TempData["Message"]` to store values and on every page do this-

```
 if (TempData["Message"] != null)
 {
   ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
 }
```

Now in the View,

```
        <div>
            @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
            {
                <div>Saved!</div>
            }
       </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this solution but this did not work I am afraid.